# Amazon Route 53 nameservers change failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, nameservers, amazon-route53

I recently transferred my domain from namecheap.com to amazon route 53 via gandi.
When doing the transfer I left my current DNS nameservers intact using:
ns1.dzfav.net
ns2.dzfav.net

Now that the transfer is complete. I wish to use Amazon Route 53 nameservers:
ns-2048.awsdns-64.com
ns-2049.awsdns-65.net
ns-2050.awsdns-66.org
ns-2051.awsdns-67.co.uk

But whenever I try to update my nameservers. I always get an email telling me that the update failed.
"We're sorry to report that the operation failed for some reason after we forwarded your request to our registrar partner."

Can anybody help me please

Comment: Who is the email from? amazon?

Comment: yes. the email came from amazon

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the e-mail (I've experienced the same problems) it is due to a pending update of the domain's registrant.

Normally this process only takes up to five days after the transfer initially occurred.

You should notice an excerpt in the Route53 e-mail which reads "2304: Domain status 'pendingUpdate - Domain pending registrant update' prohibits operation"

You might notice that this would not have occurred if you simply said "yes" to point your domain to Amazon when you started the transfer. This is only because that information would have gone through to the registrar with the small changes which every provider enforces differently on the WHOIS records/registrant information.

I hope this helps :) ...a bit too late but might help future readers hehe